# Is Batman Vol. 2 finished?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, the-new-52

Is the *New 52* *Batman Vol. 2* finished?

If it is, has it been compiled into one book?

If it is not, which hardcover books are part of it?

Comment: Surely there is a rule against questions like these. In due time, this question will be irrelevant, no?

Comment: @ghotiandchips All questions are irrelevant in due time, my friend.

Comment: @MishaRosnach As long as society exists, and a site like Stack Exchange remains relevant, the answer to [Why does the Joker always laugh](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/107600/73512) will always be relevant. In a year's time, or two years, or ten years, this asker's question will be asking a question about a volume of Batman that has been finished.

Comment: -cont'd- it's the same reason speculation questions about trailers or upcoming movies on the Movies SE are considered off-topic, too. Don't much care to contribute to this question, the gaping irrelevance and off-topic nature of this question's title merely caught my attention.

Comment: @ghotiandchips Oi... i dunno, it's just a question that relates to the topic of the website. Plus, it has a non-obvious answer that is tough to find among the google noise. If we only ask questions that will forever remain questions, like why does the Joker always laugh, this website would be wholly intolerable. As I see it, if you are looking for an objective answer that relates to the topic, ask away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Batman Vol 2](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_Vol_2) was a 52 edition series that went on from The Start of the New 52 up until Rebirth. Although The New 52 has ended and has become Rebirth, the story continues into [Batman: Rebirth Vol 1 #1](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman:_Rebirth_Vol_1_1), which in turn continues on into [Batman Volume 3](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_Vol_3).

Volume 2 has not been compiled into a book, however has been compiled into 10 collections. Which can be found [here](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Batman_Vol_2/Collections).